# Find a Facebook Page using lat/lon of the Place

Tags: facebook, api, coordinates, facebook-page

I'm creating the mobile application, and I have a crowdsourced DB with approximate lat/lon for each Place (pub, cafe, restaurant etc...) and address of the place.

What I need to do further - connect this Place with appropriate FB page (or at least try to do that). But I can't find any public API available which allows me to do it. Can anyone point me to the right direction or suggest a workaround?

Comment: Could you maybe provide some sample code of what you've already tried and where you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks, Todd. Actually, Andrew's answer below is exactly what I was looking for - just an API example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Facebook Graph search functionality with 'type' set as 'place' and 'center' containing the latitude/longitude values.
E.g.:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=*insert access token*

This will provide you a list of nearby locations. E.g: 
{

```
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Dolores Park",
         "location": {
            "street": "18th St & Dolores St",
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "state": "CA",
            "country": "United States",
            "zip": "94110",
            "latitude": 37.75956104478,
            "longitude": -122.42694721103
         },
         "category": "Landmark",
         "id": "105687759464007"
      }
      ....
```

Once you have the id, you can then use it to get more information (e.g. the page url) via the Graph API. E.g.:
http://graph.facebook.com/105687759464007